# JavaFX Image and Text not serializable

Tags: java, serialization, javafx, deserialization

Currently I'm trying to be able to save a file for a program that I'm making, although I was getting a NotSerializableException. I found out this is because javafx.scene.text.Text and javafx.scene.image.Image are not serializable. Is there another way to work around this issue or solve it, or if there are other libraries that can work just as well?

Comment: persist the string-text rather than the text node, persist the image url or file path instead of the image class.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand.
To clarify what the context of all this is, I am trying to essentially save a list. Within the list are objects, each one with its own image and text. The text and image of the object are shown on the program, depending on which I choose to select. I don't quite get what you mean by persist the string-text and persist the image url.

Comment: I think @QuyenTran gave a good idea to start with. As you asked your question and without your code snippet doing the persisting, it's just a guess for us and we can't really help you. Try to strip your code to a [MCVE] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you don't know what persistence is, then [learn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)).  For an example of how to achieve it in the context of a JavaFX program, study the [makery tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part5/).